# Get data-attribute of paper-checkbox on on-tap event

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<paper-checkbox data-id$="{{id}}" on-tap="done" checked="[[isDone]]">Done</paper-checkbox>
```

Note that the `paper-checkbox` is not contained within a `<template is="dom-repeat" ...>`

How can I get the value of `data-id` in the `done(e)` method?

I expected it would work with:

```
e.target.dataset.id
```

But it didn't... How to access that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was more interesting than I'd expected :).

There is no special convention for accessing `data-x` attributes like the `dataset.x` you tried. To get that value you need to use the standard `getAttribute()` method.

Weirdly enough, to access the attribute you need to get it from the event target's parent node which is the `<paper-checkbox>`. The target is a div inside of it.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  tapped: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id'));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
  <link href="paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html" rel="import" />
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <paper-checkbox data-id="x" on-tap="tapped"></paper-checkbox>      
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you investigation and your answer, it works.

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to keep an eye on [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-checkbox/issues/150) I created. If and when fixed, you'll have to change your code

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will do so!